# Why circular arc is disorted if canvas has height?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a circular arc in `<canvas>` element. But for some reason the resulting arc is elliptical instead of circular.

Edit: As per *Darren Sweeney*'s answer below, it seem height for canvas is issue. But I need height in my layout. Any workaround for that? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
.canvas{width:400px; height:400px; background:#ccc;}
```

**jQuery**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height/2;
var radius = 50;
var startAngle = 0 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise = false;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
context.lineWidth = 2;

// line color
context.strokeStyle = '#eeeeee';
context.stroke();
```

Following is link to jsFiddle demo : [***Click Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/zwsh12oy/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't resize the canvas element with CSS. This is causing your distortion because CSS resizing "stretches" the pixels (stretches your circle into an ellipse). The default size of html canvas is 300x150.

Instead resize the canvas element directly using it's width & height properties.

```
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Or in JavaScript

```
var canvas=getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width=400;
canvas.height=400;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css and all is good:

```
.canvas{width:400px; height: auto; background:#ccc;}
```

**Note** You can set the height, as long as it's half the width then the ratio will stay true, e.g.:

```
.canvas{width:400px; height: 200px; background:#ccc;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my website I need height for canvas! Do you know any workaround for that?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't restict my canvas to that height. The aspect ratio is much bigger!

Comment: Please update your question with exact requirements, I've answered what you've asked but now there's more...the more I know the more I can try help

Comment: No, it's not, You said you need height, my solution gives you height - do you need a certain height? If so, what? Does it have to be square?